# Error in using tidyr::fill()

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to use `tidyr::fill()` but for some reason I always get an error. Following is the example from `fill()` documentation that I am running in RStudio 1.1.383:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Month = 1:12, Year = c(2000, rep(NA, 11)))
df %>% fill(Year)
Error in fillVector(data[[col]]) : object '_tidyr_fillDown' not found
```

I have restarted R session and tried again but still get the same error.

Comment: Reinstall/update `tidyr`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Works for me. Is this method available? Check `tidyr:::\`_tidyr_fillDown\``. If not reinstall package

Comment: I had to reinstall R to make it work. Thanks.